# RPI freeze with external HDD

Tags: ssh, pi-2, hard-drive

I have an RPI 2 Model B. I just started to use it. I am connecting to it using SSH. I have an internal HDD and also a dock. The dock has it's own power source and transmits the data from the HDD to a computer using an USB cable. When I connect it to my RPI, it works great, but after a time the PI stops responding. It doesn't even answer to PING.

Can you point me to the right direction on how to start discovering the problem?

Is there any log files for these cases? I've verified all the logs in the `/var/log` folder, but there was nothing about this error.

Comment: Make sure you are using a good power source for your raspi, and that the HD has it's own power. Your raspi could also be overheating. Do you have an overclock?

Comment: No, I am not using any overclock. The dock has its own power source (separate from RPI). How to test my RPI temperature? How should I know if the RPI has a good power source?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a 3.5" dock then it might be only powered on 12V rail and drawing 5V from RPi which might not supply enough power and hence shutdown/hang.

Comment: This dock support 3.5" and 2.5" HDDs, currently I am using a 2.5" HDD. Do you think this can cause the problem described? How can I test if this is the problem?

Comment: The same thing still applies. Usually HDDs have power details somewhere on the label. AFAIK RPi 2 can supply 1.2A on all 4 USB ports And the total power is limited to 2A by a fuse. So you need a power adapter that can supply both your HDD and around 800mA for the RPi.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am going to check the HDD about power consumption. Since I am a starter with the power consumption issues (I am using a simple micro-usb cable), can you please explain me more about this? What other cable should I use? How should I supply power for my RPI? Currently the USB cable is plugged in in my router's USB port and my RPI receives power (maybe not enough). How should I test if the RPI receives enough power? Thanks!